# How to provide option to select where to save file in chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i am currently having trouble with creating an option for user to let him/her choose where they want to save files locally after clicking download button. all this is done for a chrome extension that places a button in a specific website and downloads files from that page.
I am able to make it work for a folder i create on my own but don't know how to let users choose where they want to save files.

here is my code:

```
chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(function(item, suggest) {
  if (getLocation(item.url).hostname == "balle.ac.in" || getLocation(item.url).hostname == "37.221.102.132")
  {
    suggest({filename: "Downloads"+ "/" + subject_name + "/" + teacher_name + "/" + item.filename.split("_").slice(4).join("_")});
    console.log(getLocation(item.url).hostname);
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename` is too late to show Save As dialog, since you "places a button in a specific website and downloads files from that page", you could use [chrome.downloads.download](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-download) instead.

> If both filename and saveAs are specified, then the Save As dialog will be displayed, pre-populated with the specified filename.